# How to consume DataSet response from a SOAP service in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-ksoap2

I've been using SOAP based services in a lot of Android apps and they always work fine (string output usually). However, I've come across a service that accepts a DataSet and SQL Query as input and returns a DataSet as output.

From what I know of Android, there is no DataSet object type present. My question is, how do we utilize such a service in Android? Is it even possible to do so?

Here is a snapshot of the service:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Gladly for you, you can interface Android with ASP.NET so you can read the DataSET from your SOAP WebService

I'll give a snippet

```
public class CallSoap 
{
public final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Add";

public  final String OPERATION_NAME = "Add"; 

public  final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

public  final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://yoururl/File.asmx";
public CallSoap() 
{ 
}
public String Call(int a,int b)
{
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
pi.setName("a");
        pi.setValue(a);
        pi.setType(Integer.class);
        request.addProperty(pi);
        pi=new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("b");
        pi.setValue(b);
        pi.setType(Integer.class);
        request.addProperty(pi);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;

envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
Object response=null;
try
{
httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
response = envelope.getResponse();
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
response=exception.toString();
}
return response.toString();
}
}
```

> ```
> First SOAP_ACTION = namespace as seen in figure 1+function name;
> OPERATION_NAME = name of the web method;
> WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = namespace of the webservice;
> SOAP_ADDRESS = absolute URL of the webservice;
> ```

Comment: You're saving the webservice response as an Object. Please take a look at the screenshot I attached. This service doesn't return a string or any such thing from what I understand of it. Take a look: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gv7us.jpg

Comment: Err that's what I've been using for the past year to consume webservices. Problem is, this is NOTHING like all the other services I've used in the past. For one, it doesn't return a string. I don't know what an "xsd:schema" is for starters.